# Should security be a prime issue on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion

I just was reading this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636809/java-throughput-increase-with-increasing-message-size), and it occured to me that many of the questions I look at on this site focus on how to do things that will maximize performance. But with all the frameworks out there (ie. Spring, Gigaspaces, Cloud, etc) performance seems like a relatively solved problem, and that maybe in the wake of things like heartbleed and the bash bug they should really be about minimizing vulnerabilities.

I realize these are not mutually exclusive goals, and that it's not up to me/us to say what kinds of questions we should be dealing with, but I wonder if there might be a way to systematically focus those posting questions on good techniques for build solid, well-tested technology and steering away from ideas/areas that have a history of being hard to write or buggy in implementation?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Uh...you mean like artificially limiting, or at least directing, the scope of questions/answers into a particular direction possibly not congruent with the intention of the asker/answerer? I don't think so. And why wasn't this asked on [meta.so]?

Comment: Any thoughts?  Uh, why do new clothes smell the way they do?  Doesn't matter what type or where they come from, they all have a very similar smell.  Is there a New Clothes smell that manufacturers spray them with?  What's up with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't really tell people on what they should focus when writing programs (and security will not be on the top of most peoples list, for a variety of reasons).

If users have performance issues, they will post a question about performance. If they have issues with the readability of code, the will post a question about that. And if they have issues with security, they will ask about that.

If you do see that code is insecure, I would definitely **leave a comment** pointing this out, and maybe directing them to [security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/). (if you see that they are using outdated technology, you might also point that out in a comment).